# How to use template binding inside data template in custom control (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, datatemplate, templatebinding

I am trying to create control which will take `ItemsSource` and `InnerTemplate` and will show all the items wrapped in `CheckBox`es.

The control has 2 dependency properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CheckBoxWrapperList), null);
public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InnerTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CheckBoxWrapperList), null);
```

and here is the template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CheckBoxWrapperList">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="wrapper">
                <CheckBox>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding InnerTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" />
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource wrapper}" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, this approach does not work.
Binding in the `ControlPresenter.ContentTemplate` using `TemplateBinding` does not work.
However, when I don't use template binding and reference the template as static resource, then it works as expected.

- Why cannot I use the template binding inside the content presenter in datatemplate?
- What am I missing here? Any special markup required?
- Is there a way to achieve the expected behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you figured out this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TemplateBinding can only be used within a ControlTemplate, you're using it within a DataTemplate. (The fact that the DataTemplate is within a ControlTemplate doesn't matter)

Answer (score 23):

**Silverlight and WPF**

You can get around this with a relative source binding:

Instead of:

```
{TemplateBinding InnerTemplate}
```

You would use:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CheckBoxWrapperList}, Path=InnerTemplate}
```

It's a bit messier but it works.

**WinRT**

WinRT doesn't have AncestorType. I've got *something* that works but it's kind of horrifying.

You can use an attached property to store a TemplateBinding value and then access it using ElementName...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CheckBoxWrapperList">
    <Grid x:Name="TemplateGrid" magic:Magic.MagicAttachedProperty="{TemplateBinding InnerTemplate}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="wrapper">
                <CheckBox>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=TemplateGrid, Path=(magic:Magic.MagicAttachedProperty)}" Content="{Binding}" />
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource wrapper}" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I don't know if there's a better way for WinRT.

Comment: @P.W. Urgh that's messy. Um. I've worked out something that technically works, adding to answer.