# Using TemplateBinding inside DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I'm creating a custom control, and I'm having problems binding UI elements inside a DataTemplate to the custom control's dependency properties.

There's a content control in my control that should change its content and content template according to a certain property, so I bound it this way -

```
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding ControlMode}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
```

The Content Template selector is defined this way -

```
<ns:TemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector">
      <ns:TemplateSelector.Template1>
         <DataTemplate>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding TreeSource}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ns:TemplateSelector.Template1>
      <ns:TemplateSelector.Template2>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ListSource}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ns:TemplateSelector.Template2>
</ns:TemplateSelector>
```

The problem is that the TreeView and the ListView can't be bound to their itemssource with TemplateBinding due to this error for example -

"Cannot find TreeSourceProperty on the type ContentPresenter"

I've been looking around for an answer and I found this answer that simple states that this is impossible.

[How to use template binding inside data template in custom control (Silverlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635216/how-to-use-template-binding-inside-data-template-in-custom-control-silverlight)

So if this really is impossible, how else could I bind the elements inside my template to the DependencyProperties of the CustomControl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF you can use a binding with [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) targeting the "templated" control.

e.g.

```xml
{Binding TreeSource,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyCustomControl}}
```

**Edit:** If you have a break in a tree you could possibly work around that by passing that control around, e.g.

```
<ControlThatOwnsPopup
    Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyCustomControl}}">
     <Popup>...
```

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.TreeSource,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Popup}}"/>
```

Comment: Yes this would work in a regular condition, but I forgot to mention that my CustomControl opens a popup (actually more of a window-popup), and this ContentControl actually resides in the popup, so finding the CustomControl in its ancestors will not work as it's not on the same logical tree.