# DataGrid in TabItem's ContentTemplate loses selected entry and scroll position

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol, tabitem

I've got `MyDataGrid`, derived from `DataGrid` in `ContentTemplate` of `TabItem`:

```
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyDataGrid ItemsSource={Binding CurrentTab.Collection}>
                ...
            </MyDataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl>
```

(`CurrentTab` is current model object in my ViewModel and `Collection` is `ObservableCollection`). The issue is that when I switch tab item to another and switch back to first one, items that were selected/in view port aren't selected and `DataGrid` is scrolled to the start.

Also: [WPF TabControl and DataGrid bugs, bugs and bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876890/wpf-tabcontrol-and-datagrid-bugs-bugs-and-bugs) (first "bug")

Comment: Isn't the CurrentTab binding changing when you switch the tab?

Comment: Yes, `CurrentTab` changes when I switch the tab.

Comment: Then I think you are loosing the binding in MyDataGrid ItemSource. Maybe with a little more code will be easier to help.

Comment: Hmm, don't get it, what means loosing the binding? All the data which should be displayed for different tabs is displayed properly, the issue is loosing selected item and current view port. There is my XAML: http://pastebin.com/vpxB0Dgd

Comment: I mean that you are changing the ItemSource of your DataGrid every time you change the tab, maybe this is causing a reInitialization of the grid and then you loose the selected item, because when you init a DataGrid, it hasn't SelectedItem by default.

Comment: Try binding your itemsource to tab1.Collection, tab2.Collection...Etc, instead of currentTab.Collection.

Comment: @Kirenenko hmm If I will bind to something like tab1..tab2 there will no sense in that template stuff :D

Comment: @Kirenenko may be there is some way to create several DataGrids for each templated tab item...

Comment: Then you should give the correspondant tab source when you use the template. Give me some code of the use of the template if you want more explanations.

Comment: ViewModel: http://pastebin.com/P5PgHSiz, XAML: http://pastebin.com/vpxB0Dgd

Comment: There is so much code mate...Im not going to study all of that. I'll give you the clue in a response, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TemplateBinding` in your Template, then pass your correspondant Tab or collection when you use it in every tab.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9780506/5147720) out for more info.